# Multiple arb files with the same 'en' locale detected. Ensure that there is exactly one arb file for each locale

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, intl

After Two weeks I opened my project. My coworker made some big changes. But when I update the project from GitHub, This Error occurred. it doesn't generate Internationalize files.

[image]

I tried to run `flutter gen-l10n` but here's the output
[image]

And here are the files inside the l10n folder

[image]

Now how can I solve it??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to disable the Flutter intl extension and generate code manually using `flutter gen-l10n`

Answer (score 0):

you have to english files just delete one of them

Comment: After deleteing intl_en_US.arb it show the same 'Multible arb' error

Answer (score 0):

In your project (or your language folder) there are at least 2 files with key and value like this "@@locale": "en".
you just need to check each file and make sure each file has its own value at the key "@@locale".

I had the same problem and fixed it this way.
My cause is because I used the tool to merge 2 arb files on https://codezi.pro/merge-arb-file but forgot to change this key value after having a new merge file.
Hope this helps others who have the same problem